# Create class for imported SWC elements

Tags: actionscript-3, movie, swc

I have imported a SWC into my actionscript project. It includes many different movieclips that I can access in my project. My question is this: How can I create a custom AS3 class that I can use to add functions and properties to my movieclips?

For example I have a movieclip with a linkage name of LevelButton. I tried creating a class that was the same name but they didn't seem to go together.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by generating the .SWC with proper linkage names on my movieclip. Then in my application I created a class that extending the movieclip.

ie. Movieclip with linkage name: `MyMovieclip_mc`

then my application class:

```
public class MyMovieclip extends MyMovieclip_mc
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the class before you generate the SWC and then it'll get compiled into the it. if you don't supply a class, Flash will use an empty class of its own.

you can't do this afterwards ...

```
public class LevelButton extends MovieClip
{
  // ...
  public function myCustomFunction():void
  {
    // do sth here
  }
}
```

and then you can just say:

```
var lvlBtn:LevelButton = new LevelButton();
lvlBtn.myCustomFunction();
```

Comment: Really? that stinks, That in a way seems counter intuitive when I am wanting to keep my actionscript project separate from my assets project. Is there anyway to add properties and functions to the class afterward?

Comment: you may try and extend the class ... but i've never done that. i always have my lib.swc where i create all my visual assets and add them later (via include swc to class path) to my classes that implement the whole functionality.